# print the entire json data in onMessage() android

Tags: android

I want to print the entire json data in onMessage() of the broadcast receiver

```
{
    "apiKey": "b3ca79eb-dede-4c58-a163-cdfbfcc081a4",
    "appKey": "81047fab-715f-47d9-a6cd-cb7e544bb30e",
    "sendAll": true,
    "content": {
        "subject": "Test Lottery",
        "message": "Notification Msg",
        "action": {
            "type": "DEFAULT",
            "data": "url|intent|...",
            "labe": "label"
        },
        "payload": "{'uid':'1','type':'LD'}",
        "sound": "default.caf",
        "badge": "+1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Print where? To screen, to a specific text view, to the log? What variable holds this data you want to print, and where is that variable created? You need to post a bit more info

Comment: Log.e("TAG",yourJsonString);